# Android libGDX - android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I am having android app using libgdx and tried to implement google play services. When I turn on an emulator, it's just appears black screen. Go to Android Monitor and this shows up:

```
09-22 11:56:48.140 1571-1571/? E/MobileDataStateTracker: default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
09-22 11:56:48.140 1571-1571/? E/MobileDataStateTracker: default: Could not enable APN type "default"
09-22 11:56:56.777 1861-1975/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
09-22 11:56:59.757 1861-1975/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
09-22 11:57:01.687 2159-2174/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzappprovider
09-22 11:57:03.467 1861-2219/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
09-22 11:57:06.017 1861-2219/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
09-22 11:57:34.537 1861-1861/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService has leaked ServiceConnection crs@a53b5ea8 that was originally bound here
                                                 android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService has leaked ServiceConnection crs@a53b5ea8 that was originally bound here
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1561)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1544)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
                                                     at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.zapp.ZappLogOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509030:1)
                                                     at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509030:2)
                                                     at bvr.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509030:10)
                                                     at bvo.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509030:14)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-22 12:13:57.597 2765-2765/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-22 12:13:57.597 2765-2765/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-22 12:13:57.617 1571-1600/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a534dd00 com.squareit.pupindev/com.squareit.pupindev.AndroidLauncher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I thought that it was from implementing Play Services and Google Ads but I removed all dependencies and code from gradle files and Android Launcher, so my gradle files look like this:

**Project:**

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "SquareIt"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
//        compile project(":BaseGameUtils")

        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'

//        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2'
//        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.2.2'
//        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.2.2'
//        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
//        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.2.2"

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"


    }
}




project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

**Android module:**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 26
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.squareit.pupindev"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

}
```

Here is **AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication** *onCreate method*:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(mainGame = new Squareit(this), config);


    }
```